# Prove that the groups $H/(H\cap K)$ and $HK/K$ are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a group with normal subgroups H,K. Consider the normal subgroups  $(H\cap K)$ and $HK$. Prove that the groups $H/(H\cap K)$ and $HK/K$ are isomorphic.

---

I'm pretty sure I need to use the fundamental isomorphism theorem for groups, but I'm not really sure how to start the problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea: $~A/B\cong C\iff$ there is a surjection $A\to C$ with kernel $B$.

For $H/(H\cap K)\cong HK/K$, what groups need to be $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: $A=H, B=(H\cap K), C = HK/K$

Comment: So I need to find an onto homomorphism from $H\rightarrow HK/K$ which has kernel $(H\cap K)$.

Comment: Yes. Can you think of what the map should be?

Comment: Is it $\phi(h)=(hk)K=hK$?

Comment: I don't know what you think you mean by $(hk)K$ (where'd little $k$ come from?) but the map is indeed $h\mapsto hK$.

Comment: $hk\in HK$. I meant $(hk)K$ to be a coset of $K$ in $HK$.

Comment: The elements of $HK$ do indeed look like $hk$. However we are starting with an element of $H$ and ending with a coset of $K$ in $HK$; at no point do we pick up a made-up mysterious little $k$ when we are constructing our homomorphism $H\to HK/K$.

Comment: But aren't all of the elements $HK/K$ cosets of $K$ in $HK$ which would look like $(hk)K$? Sorry if this seems strange, I'm new at this.

Comment: Yes they do look like that. And $hK$ is of that form, since it is $he_KK$. However when you say $\phi(h)=(hk)K$ you are writing down some unknown specific element $k\in K$, for no reason. Simply say $\phi(h)=hK$ and be done with it.

Comment: I see. Now I'm just not sure why $\ker(\phi)$ is $(H\cap K)$. The identity coset would be $hK$, right?

Comment: What is the identity element of $HK/K$?

Comment: Oh, isn't it just $e_{HK}K$?

Comment: You're writing so many strangely unnecessary things. The identity element is simply $K$. Under what conditions does $hK=K$?

Comment: It just helps if I see the same structure as in the book, I guess. I understand they are the same though. I need to find the elements of $H$ which are taken to $K$ by $\phi$, and if the element is in both it will be taken to $K$

Comment: $hK=K$ if and only if $h\in K$. Which $h\in H$ are in $K$? Easy: the elements $h\in H\cap K$.

Comment: Right, thank you very much. You have been incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: define a map $\phi: H \rightarrow HK/K$, by $\phi(h)=hK$ and show that this is a surjective homomorphism with $ker(\phi)=H \cap K$. Then apply the first isomorphism theorem.