# Quotient group of product $HK$ over $H$ where $H,K$ are normal, is isomorphic to $K/({K\cap H})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In order to prove that

$H/({K\cap H}) \cong (HK)/K $

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702503/prove-that-the-groups-h-h-cap-k-and-hk-k-are-isomorphic)

I understand that, in order to apply the first isomorphism theorem, I need to find a map from $H$ to $Kh$ such that $H\cap K$ is the kernel. Then, by the theorem, we have the isomorphism.

But how to prove $\phi: H \to HK, \ \phi(h) = hK\implies $$\ker\phi = H\cap K$?

ps: in my book, $A/B$ is all of the classes $Ba$ for $a\in A$, which is a bit different from the exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are taking a map from $\phi: H \rightarrow HK/ K$, by $\phi(h)=hK$. The elements in Im${(\phi)}$ images are cosets.

To write it more precisely (I am using additive notation to make it clear),

$\phi(h)=h e_K+K$.

Now ker ${\phi}=\{h\in H |\ he_K\in K\}$ which is exactly $H\cap K$.

Comment: Yes and in your case $HK/K=\{K.hk\}$, i.e. set of cosets

Comment: you should reread about left and right cosets once more. you are getting confused with cosets i guess

Comment: isn't there 2 ways to define quotient groups? one in term of left cosets and one in terms of rigth cosets

Comment: some people use left cosets, and others use right cosets. Tthere is a one-one correspondence between them and they are same in number. They partition the group in same way so it doesnt matter which one you work with.

Comment: With a NORMAL subgroup, the left and right cosets are the SAME (so it doesn't matter). Note that to apply the F.I.T. you need to show that the map $\phi: H \to HK/K$ given by $\phi(h) = hK = Kh$ is ONTO. This can be accomplished by showing that for $hk \in HK$, that $(hk)K = hK$, that is: $hkh^{-1} \in K$ (which is why we need $K$ to be normal).